# Write a function like printf, that can sanitize all arguments after the first to be free from the `%` symbol

Tags: c, security, printf, variadic-functions

```
user_input = "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s";
printf("user input is: %s", user_input);
```

... crash!

The above lines cause an error. I want to write a function which can be used like `printf` but can sanitize all arguments after the first to make sure they do not contain the `%` symbol. The function should be used like 'printf' in that it can take any number of arguments and it print outs a string in the same manner. If the other arguments contain the `%` symbol, I just want that symbol taken out before it is put in the format string.

If this new function were called `safe_printf`, I would want the behavior to be like this:

```
user_input = "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s";
safe_printf("user input is: %s, user_input);
```

user input is: ssssssss

It seems like writing a function like this may not be possible, (I can't figure out how to preprocess the char *s in the va_list without knowing how many there are) if that's the case please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The 'user input' shown doesn't crash `printf()`.  It might crash it if you used `printf(user_input, "just one argument")` or other variants where the user input controls the formatting.  Your `safe_printf` is called incorrectly; you have the second double quote … in the wrong place; or actually, it's missing altogether.  And your crash may be because you try to remove the percent symbols from a non-modifiable character string literal; they're not writable in general.

Comment: I was confused about the behavior of ```printf()```. I didn't realize that the format string is the only argument able to cause such a crash. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

The string formatting vulnerability exists if user provided input is passed to the `printf(3)` function. You can prevent this by not allowing that happen, *ever*. There is absolutely not reason to have a dynamic format string because you should know ahead of time the required format, and therefore you can put the format string in read only memory through the use of a `const char *`